# first, second and third derivative of a vector function

Tags: derivatives, matlab, partial-derivative, vectors, maple

I can define the following vector function

$f(x,y,z) = [x^2  - 1, x^3 + y^2, z]$

in MatLab or in Maple.

I want to find (and evaluate) the first, second and third derivatives of it. How to find : $\nabla{f}$, $\nabla^2{f}$ and $\nabla^3{f}$? Here vector function $f$ is differentiated with respect to vector $(x,y,z)$. I can do the simple job of finding $\nabla{f}$ with Maple as follows :

$f(x,y,z) := [x^2  - 1, x^3 + y^2, z]$

$\nabla{f} := Jacobian (f,[x,y,z])$

But how to differentiate $\nabla{f}$?

Is there a function in MatLab (or in Maple) which may take the above function as an input and evaluate its derivatives for a given value of (x,y,z)?

Thank you.

Comment: With respect to what? $x$?

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully I have understood your correctly.

The procedure `T` below will produce an Array of expressions. And `T` can be called again (recursively) to get the higher derivatives.

The `unapply` command can create appliable procedures from the results, as one way to evaluate subsequently at given points in (x,y,z) space.

```
restart:

f:=[x^3-1,x^3*y^2-y^3,z^2*x*y^2]; # alternatively Array([x^2-1,x^3-y^3,z])

                      [ 3       3  2    3   2    2]
                 f := [x  - 1, x  y  - y , z  x y ]


T:=proc(A::{Array,list},L::list(name))
    Array(op(ArrayTools:-Dimensions(A)),1..nops(L),
          ()->diff(A[args[1..nargs-1]],L[args[-1]]));
end proc:


ans1 := T(f,[x,y,z]); # Jacobian

                     [    2                           ]
                     [ 3 x           0           0    ]
                     [                                ]
                     [   2  2     3        2          ]
             ans1 := [3 x  y   2 x  y - 3 y      0    ]
                     [                                ]
                     [  2  2        2                2]
                     [ z  y      2 z  x y     2 z x y ]


func1 := unapply(ans1,[x,y,z]):

func1(3,5,7);

                         [  27     0     0]
                         [                ]
                         [ 675   195     0]
                         [                ]
                         [1225  1470  1050]

ans2 := T(ans1,[x,y,z]):

ans2[..,..,1],ans2[..,..,2],ans2[..,..,3];

      [ 6 x      0       0   ]  [  0         0          0   ]  
      [                      ]  [                           ]  
      [     2     2          ]  [   2       3               ]  
      [6 x y   6 x  y    0   ], [6 x  y  2 x  - 6 y     0   ], 
      [                      ]  [                           ]  
      [           2         2]  [   2         2             ]  
      [  0     2 z  y  2 z y ]  [2 z  y    2 z  x    4 z x y]  

        [  0        0       0   ]
        [                       ]
        [  0        0       0   ]
        [                       ]
        [     2                2]
        [2 z y   4 z x y  2 x y ]


func2 := unapply(ans2,[x,y,z]):

val := func2(3,5,7):

val[..,..,1], val[..,..,2], val[..,..,3];

          [ 18    0    0]  [  0    0    0]  [  0    0    0]
          [             ]  [             ]  [             ]
          [450  270    0], [270   24    0], [  0    0    0]
          [             ]  [             ]  [             ]
          [  0  490  350]  [490  294  420]  [350  420  150]


ans3 := T(ans2,[x,y,z]):

ans3[..,..,3,2], map(diff,ans2[..,..,3],y);

            [  0      0      0  ]  [  0      0      0  ]
            [                   ]  [                   ]
            [  0      0      0  ], [  0      0      0  ]
            [                   ]  [                   ]
            [4 z y  4 z x  4 x y]  [4 z y  4 z x  4 x y]
```

As mentioned, `T` can be called again, on earlier results. And a recursive procedure could be written to fold that process up into a new mechanism to produce the higher derivative results directly. Or `T` could be modified as follows,

```
R:=proc(A::{Array,list},L::list(name),n::posint) local i;
      Array(op(ArrayTools:-Dimensions(A)),seq(1..nops(L),i=1..n),
            ()->diff(A[args[1..nargs-n]],L[[args[-n..-1]]][]));
   end proc:

R(f, [x,y,z], 1); # Jacobian

R(f, [x,y,z], 2):
%[..,..,1], %[..,..,2], %[..,..,3];
R(f, [x,y,z], 3):
%[..,..,3,2], map(diff,R(f,[x,y,z],2)[..,..,3],y);
```

And those results from `R` could also be passed to `unapply`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution to your problem.

- **syms x y z**  %you are declaring the variables which we'll be used as arguments
- **F=[x.^2-1;x.^3+y.^2;z]** %this is your vector function
- **Fx=[diff(f(1),x);diff(f(2),x);diff(f(3),x)]** %this is $\frac{dF}{dx}$
- **Fy=[diff(f(1),y);diff(f(2),y);diff(f(3),y)]** %this is $\frac{dF}{dy}$
- **Fz=[diff(f(1),z);diff(f(2),z);diff(f(3),z)]** %this is $\frac{dF}{dz}$

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Matlab, but in Maxima you can differentiate the whole vector as `diff([x.^2-1;x.^3+y.^2;z], x)` e.g.. If you build a function which from any $G$ yields `[diff(G,x); diff(G,y); diff(G,z)]`, you should be able to get the $k+1$ tensors $\nabla^k \mathbf{F}$ directly.